Why gcd$(40,3)=1$, tells us that the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism for the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$.
I was reading this page Probability that cubic of integer ends with 11 and one of the answers states:
"If $^3 ≡ 1$ mod$ 100$, then $^2 ≡ 1$ and so  is a unit mod $100$. The group of units mod $100$ has order $\phi(100)=40$. Therefore, since gcd$(40,3)=1$, the map $ \mapsto ^3$ is a bijection. Thus, there is exactly one  such that $^3≡11$ mod $100$."
My question is why the gcd$(40,3)=1$ tells us the map is bijective. I see the $3$ comes from our map being $x$ to $x^3$, but don't see why this forces it to be a bijection. (I see we can just bash this out, so the statement is indeed correct).
BTW: I didn't leave a comment on the initial page because I don't have the ability to do so.

Hint:  argue that $x^3=y^3$ would imply the existence of an element of order $3$.

Use Bézout to prove that the map is subjective.

From $\gcd(40,3)=1$, it follows that $3$ is invertible mod $40$, so there exists $a$ such that $3a\equiv1\bmod40$, so $x\mapsto x^a$ is an inverse of $x\mapsto x^3$ for units $x$ mod $100$

The group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$ (its multiplicative group, if you like) has order $\phi(100)=\phi(2^2)\phi(5^2)=2\cdot 5\cdot 4=40$. If $x^3=y^3$ then $x=y$ or $xy^{-1}$ has order $3$. Suppose $x\ne y$ so $xy^{-1}$ has order $3$. The order of an element must divide the order of the group, so $3|40$ but this is a contradiction as $\operatorname{gcd}(3,40)=1$. So, the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is injective. Since we are talking about finite sets, an injective map $(\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})^\times$ to itself must be bijective, so it is an automorphism.

Oh I see. Thank you! So the initial poster implied that since the gcd is one, there is no element of order three which we would need if the map was not a bijection.
Is this step required in the logic and the original poster skipped it due to triviality, or is there another way to think about it?

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
